# How can I change verification email on Xbox Live?

Tags: xbox-network

I went to cancel automatic Gold subscription renewal (a sad moment in my life to be sure), and Microsoft emailed me a confirmation code that I had to copy/paste into a form to confirm the cancellation.

Interestingly, the email went to an old email address of mine. I've looked through my account on xbox.com and I can't find any remaining references to that email address. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked your microsoft account with same login details for references of the old email?

Comment: @3ventic yeah, I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your contact email for all Microsoft products including Xbox Live at [Microsoft's Commerce Site](http://commerce.microsoft.com) now.

Steps:

1. Go to [commerce.microsoft.com](http://commerce.microsoft.com).
2. Login to Your account.
3. Click on Profile.
4. Click on Edit Profile.
5. Change Email Address.
6. Confirm Email Address change.
7. Grab a sangwich for your efforts and ENJOY IT.

Answer (score 0):

These emails will go to your "Billing Contact" email.

From the "My Account" section of Xbox.com, click on "Billing Contact Information" in the left column.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately for me, that has my current email address set already.

Comment: Weird... I tried changing it, and it changed where the emails were sent for me. :( Sorry.